# Is Stream Binded?

Tags: c#, winforms, io, stream

I came across an exception while trying to do my stream to assign to another and dispose it as below

```
Stream str = new FileStream(somefile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
Stream newstr = str;
str.Dispose(); // I disposed only str and not new str

byte[] b = new byte[newstr.Length];// got exception here stating unable to access closed stream...
```

Why......? I am new to C# and `Stream` where `Stream` is in namespace `System.IO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you call `str.Dispose`, `newStr` is also disposed. This is because `Stream`, like all classes in .NET, are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx). When you write `Stream newstr = str`, you are not creating a new `Stream`, you are simply creating a new reference to the *same* `Stream`.

The correct way to write this would be:

```
Stream str = new FileStream(somefile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
int strLen = str.Length;
str.Dispose(); 

byte[] b = new byte[strLen];
```

This will avoid any `ObjectDisposedException`'s. Note that `int` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), so when you write `int strLen = str.Length` you *are* creating a new copy of the value, and saving it in the variable `strLen`. So even after the `Stream` is disposed, you can use that value.